# Can I split defaultConfig in multiple blocks?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My `defaultConfig` block is growing thanks to multiple configurations for libraries. Room, for example, needs an `annotationProcessorOptions`.

Trying to get a clearer config, I created a second `defaultConfig` block in the bottom of `android` block and threw Room configuration there, followed by an also needed `sourceSets` block. It seems to be working.

Is there any issue on splitting my `defaultConfig` in multiple declaration blocks? I couldn't find any documentation regarding that.